# Why matplotlib subplots does not show xtick labels when second y-axis is added?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot, yaxis

Why matplotlib subplots does not show x-tick labels when second y-axis is added? It only shows x-tick labels for the last subplot! When I comment ax2=ax.twinx(), it will show x-tick labels, but I need the second y-label as well!

```
n_subplots=2
fig, axar = plt.subplots(n_subplots, 1,figsize=(10,8), dpi=100)
# fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35, wspace=0.2)        

df1 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))
df2 = pd.Series(np.random.rand(10))

for i in range(n_subplots):
    ax = axar[i]


    df1.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
    ax.set_xticklabels((df1.index)*10)

    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.set_xticklabels((df1.index)*10)
    ax2.set_ylim(bottom=0, top=10)
    # df2.plot(kind='line', secondary_y=True, ax=ax2)
```

Comment: Just a minor question: Where are you plotting `df2`? I don't see it. Also, you don't need for loop for just 2 subplots.

Comment: Why not a for-loop for 2 subplots? It's the DRY way to do it. However, it would be better to write `for ax in axar` instead of `for i in range(n_subplots): ax = axar[i]`.

Comment: @Bazingaa I have lots of plots (figures), each with 5 subplots. To simplify, I coded with only two subplots. Also, I didn't plot df2, just for simplicity. But, the problem will be the same!

Comment: @Joooeey: You are right, but actually, my code was totally different, when I simplified it, I forgot to do that. Thank you